# Mostrar dato de array según dato anterior

Tags: php

Les comento, estoy haciendo una web aobre los juegos olimpicos. Estoy usando *Simple Html Dom* para extraer los datos de una fuente. Pero ahora quiero ponerle un color de fondo segun el pais.
Se me ocurrio usar dos arrays, uno con el nombre de las selecciones y otro con los colores. Pero me faltaría que el color se muestre si cumple con el pais.

Este lo que logré hacer, sin embargo no cumple con lo que deberia.

```
$arrayequipos = ['Ecuador Sub-23', 'Chile Sub-23'];
$arraycolores = ['254, 205, 1', '198, 39, 58'];

<svg style="width: 100%; height: 100%;position: absolute;">
    <line x1="15%" y1="110%" x2="70%" y2="-10%" style="stroke:rgb(<?php        
  if ($arrayequipos[0]==$anombre[0]) {
  echo $arraycolores[0];
    # code...
  }
; ?>);stroke-width:40"></line>
</svg>
```

Comment: Podes agregarle un `'style="background-color:'.$arraycolores[i]` y con eso salir del apuro. Pero la *manera correcta* es definir todos los cores en el css de la pagina, y solo aplicarle la clase al div q corresponda.

Comment: el diseño ya lo tengo todo listo, y no puedo usar [i] porque ya uso un for anteriormente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Miren, lo resolví

```
<svg style="width: 100%; height: 100%;position: absolute;">
  <line x1="15%" y1="110%" x2="70%" y2="-10%" style="stroke:rgb(
    <?php
      for ($i2 = 0; $i2 <= 9; $i2++) {
        if ($arrayequipos[$i2]==$anombre[0]) {
          echo $arraycolores[$i2];
        }
      }
    ?>
      );stroke-width:40">
   </line>
</svg>
```

¿Que hace este codigo?
Primero un for para recorrer el vector, y adentro una comparación con un `if` para ver que cumpla e imprima lo que necesito.

Pero yo me pregunto: ¿Esto es muy lento? ¿Hay alguna forma de optimizarlo más?